# Не ясна работа кода относительно слайса в key

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Код

```
class L:
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(key)
        print(value)

l = L()
l[:] = []
```

В Python 2.7 возвращает

```
slice(0, 9223372036854775807, None)
[]
```

В 3+

```
slice(None, None, None)
[]
```

Не могу понять суть. В чем она? И зачем вообще так

```
l[:] = []
```

делать?

Ссылка на оригинал кода https://github.com/mailpile/Mailpile/blob/0989ac1fe341d969ab2cc4d35af5625b3a122964/mailpile/config/base.py#L528

Comment: Логически порассуждаю — в Python 2 у типа int были физические пределы (вот это длинное число — это 2**63-1), в Python 3 int сделали бесконечным, а так как бесконечность невозможно записать в виде целого числа (float'ы не в счёт), то, видимо, обозначение отсутствия предела в срезе решили заменить на None

Comment: «И зачем вообще так делать?» — возможно, это связано с тем, что в Python 2 `l.clear()` ещё не существовал